# найти непрерывную последовательность в списке на основании последовательности в другом списке Python

Tags: python

list1 = [1,5,6,7,8,9,0,**9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2**]
list2 = [**9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2**,1,0,3,5,2,5,7]

В списке list2 с начала массива идет последовательность (выделена жирным), точно такая же со сдвигом повторяется в списке list1 (выделена жирным). Мне достаточно 3-4 совпадений подряд, чтобы понять, что последовательность верная. Вернуть нужно правильные индексы из списка list1. Списки короткие для примера, в реальности они могут быть по 300-400 значений, сдвиг может быть на 100-200 индексов и значения могут быть пятизначными. Сами значения в списках в верной последовательности могут немного колебаться (примерно +3, -3), поэтому внутри сравнения надо еще проверять на эти колебания.  Подскажите, есть ли решения на Python для этого?

Comment: У вас одна последовательность в  листе, или же может быть несколько последовательностей, которые в рандомном порядке содержатся в списке 1 и в списке 2? ... если так, то может одна последовательность наехать на другую?

Comment: вероятность того что последовательность повториться, мала, поэтому пока это не учитываю. просто две последовательности цифр, которое в какой-то момент начинают совпадать. все осложняется тем, что в массивах числа могут быть близко похожи, но не идентичны. например: 1000 - 1002, 15 - 12 и т.п.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не уверен насколько правильно я Вас понял, но возможно такой вариант подходит под такую задачу:

```
def find(list1, list2, tolerance=3, min_sequence_length=3):
    result_sequence = []
    current_sequence = []

    for i in range(len(list1)):
        for j in range(len(list2)):
            k = 0
            current_sequence = []

            while (i + k < len(list1) and j + k < len(list2) and
                   abs(list1[i + k] - list2[j + k]) <= tolerance):
                current_sequence.append(list1[i + k])
                k += 1

            if len(current_sequence) > len(result_sequence):
                result_sequence = current_sequence

    if len(result_sequence) >= min_sequence_length:
        return result_sequence
    return None

list1 = [1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2]
list2 = [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 3, 5, 2, 5, 7]

result = find(list1, list2)
if result:
    print("Последовательность в list1:", result)
else:
    print("Не найдено.")
```

```
>>> Последовательность в list1: [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2]
```

Если, к примеру, заменить 0 в первом списке на 12, то:

```
>>> Последовательность в list1: [12, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2]
```

Comment: да, спасибо! это именно то что нужно

Comment: Рад помочь. Если данный ответ смог решить Вашу проблему, пожалуйста, пометьте её галочкой решения и тем самым закрыв вопрос. 
Удачных разработок!

Answer (score 0):

```
def find_continuous_sequence(list1, list2, min_length=3, tolerance=3):
    def is_match(a, b):
        return abs(a - b) <= tolerance

    max_match_count = 0
    current_match_count = 0
    best_start = -1
    current_start = -1

    for i in range(len(list1)):
        for j in range(len(list2)):
            if is_match(list1[i], list2[j]):
                if current_match_count == 0:
                    current_start = i
                current_match_count += 1
                if current_match_count > max_match_count:
                    max_match_count = current_match_count
                    best_start = current_start
            else:
                current_match_count = 0

    if max_match_count >= min_length:
        return list1[best_start:best_start + max_match_count]
    else:
        return []

list1 = [1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2]
list2 = [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 3, 5, 2, 5, 7]

result = find_continuous_sequence(list1, list2)
print(result)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Добавьте в ответ результат печати `print(result)`